# Keep last word after splitting a string python

Tags: python, pandas, split

I've a column which has these type of values:

```
       'group_activity', 'dairy_revenue_freq', 'dairy_revenue',
       'livestock_revenue_freq', 'livestock_revenue',
       'poultry_revenue_freq', 'poultry_revenue',
       'fruitsandveg_revenue_freq', 'fruitsandveg_revenue',
       'cereals_revenue_freq', 'cereals_revenue',
       'cashcrops_revenue_freq', 'cashcrops_revenue',
       'aquaculture_revenue_freq', 'aquaculture_revenue',
       'roots_revenue_freq', 'roots_revenue', 'other_farming',
       'other_agric_revenue_freq', 'other_agric_revenue',
       'dairy_trading_revenue_freq', 'dairy_trading_revenue',
       'livestock_trading_revenue_freq', 'livestock_trading_revenue',
       'poultry_trading_revenue_freq', 'poultry_trading_revenue',
       'horticulture_trading_revenue_freq',
       'horticulture_trading_revenue', 'cereals_trading_revenue_freq',
       'cereals_trading_revenue', 'cashcrops_trading_revenue_freq',
       'cashcrops_trading_revenue', 'fish_trading_revenue_freq',
       'fish_trading_revenue', 'other_trading_business',
       'other_trading_revenue_freq', 'other_trading_revenue',
       'retailing_footwear_revenue_freq', 'retailing_footwear_revenue',
       'retailing_clothes_revenue_freq', 'retailing_clothes_revenue',
       'retail_kiosk_revenue_freq', 'retail_kiosk_revenue',
       'agrovet_revenue_freq', 'agrovet_revenue',
       'handicraft_revenue_freq', 'handicraft_revenue',
       'furniture_revenue_freq', 'furniture_revenue',
       'other_retailing_business', 'other_retailing_revenue_freq'...
```

I ant to split these string based on `_` and only keep the last words i.e. `activity`, `freq`, `revenue`.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
df1['a'] = df1['c'].str.split('_', 2, expand=True)[1]
```

But it is not giving the right result for all the value as the number of times `_` appears varies.

Comment: I think `df1['c'].str.split('_').str[-1]`

Comment: @ALollz sorry my bad it works :D

Comment: No problem. Happy coding